# excel IF max value in top row, then excel shows me the value from the same column in the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I need excel to find a value in the next row's cell back on the highest value of the previous cell.  Example:

```
-4%  -6%   2%    0.34%
 4%   2%   1%   -0.50%
 3%  -1%   3%      -1%
```

Above you can see that the highest value in the top row is 2%.  What I did excel to do, is simply tell me the next row in 1%.  Then for the next row I need excel to tell me 3% since the highest value in the middle row is 4%

Comment: Will there ever be a "tie" for largest value, or are the values all different on any given row?

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,1,MATCH(MAX(A1:D1),A1:D1,FALSE))
```

From the inside out:  The MAX function returns the largest value in the row.  The MATCH function returns the position of that largest value.  The INDEX function returns the same position from the next row.